# SailsJS Model.query() undefined in test

Tags: sails.js

I find that when I call `Model.query` in a Mocha test, its `undefined`. `Model.find/create` etc works. `Model.query` works when the app runs normally. Why might that be? I am using `sails-postgresql`

In my mocha test bootstrap I have already lift sails.

Comment: Could help if you posted the code you're trying to run, hard to have any idea what's going on otherwise

Comment: I found that the problem seems to be cause by sails not creating the tables at all. Somehow it manages it start ... `migrate` is alter